# Pentaho Dummy set not passing data

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to use a Dummy set in latest version of Pentaho to UNION two streams.  When I do that the next step always says "unable top find rowset"

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

First check the two flows are independently correct: Disable one of the arrow (click on it) and run on 1000 rows, then disable the other an run for an other 1000 rows.

If the incoming flows are both correct, their metadata also need to match exactly (columns, type, order of columns,...). Open the `Output fields` (right-click) and place the two windows side-by-side. The two first columns (and the mask for the date) must be exactly the same.

If you cannot change the metadata with the `Edit original step` button, put a `Select value` on the flow.

Comment: The columns match(one is a table input the other an update for the same table).  I tried inserting select after each to insure, but same results - the step afte rthe dummy says empty rowset.